# Accusative--Infinitive Construction

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, accusativus-cum-infinitivo, lucretius

Lucretius, De Natura Rerum: Liber Secundus; L177–181 contains this sentence:

> nam quamvis rerum ignorem primordia quae sint,
>   hoc tamen ex ipsis caeli rationibus ausim
>   confirmare aliisque ex rebus reddere multis,
>   nequaquam nobis divinitus esse creatam
>   naturam mundi:

Given that Lucretius is writing in the first person (eg "ignorem"; "ausim") why deploy acc-inf construction, esse creatam, which represents indirect speech?
Why not "creata est" giving the required--has-been-created; with "nequaquam" giving: has by no means been created?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps you can explain why you think first person verbs and indirect speech are incompatible.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the a.c.i. (and some other constructions) is called indirect speech. So Lucretius could have written, in a new sentence, *nequaquam divinitus est creata natura*, which would not have been indirect speech. But I think the main point here is that indirect speech is not necessarily speech from someone other than the speaker: it can be the same person.

The function of indirect speech can be to express the attitude of the speaker towards a certain statement or phrase. In this case, one could say that Lucretius expresses epistemic modality towards his theory and tells us how he come to it: he demonstrates or asserts (*confirmare*) and recounts (*reddo*) the content of his theory, the indirect speech. He takes position with regard to the theory.

Had he phrased it in direct speech, it would have been presented as a fact by default, which was not his intention. He could have qualified indirect speech in other ways to get around that; but indirect speech is a natural approach.

Compare this with how one would write the same thing in English:

> I assert **that** the gods were not involved in the creation of nature.

This is indirect speech as well, marked by the introductory word *that*. It's the natural way if you want to use a word like *assert*.

---

On a side note, the term 'direct speech' means speech exactly as it is phrased by the speaker (or *m. m.* the writer). In a way, the entire *De Rerum Natura*, like any text, is direct speech, as one can quote from it; it contains words written exactly so by Lucretius. Then indirect speech is embedded in the direct speech.